# I sent a transaction and it gave me an error then went through

Tags: security

I was sending some XMR using XMR.to
XMR.to gave me the address to send to in my monero wallet. The monero wallet went white and started thinking. It took along time. Then I'm not real clear on what exactly it said but there was a message about the transaction not going through and I hit the button on the right to send it again and it went through.

Did I just encounter a malicious node?
Does this attack I've been told about only effect one transaction?

Comment: What wallet version were you using? Do you recall what the error was?

Comment: I think my wifi cut out

Comment: @Number9 Sure. Not being connected to a node/daemon will make a transaction fail :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this could happen if your transaction got into a block that was lost due to a chain reorg.

Comment: I think my wi fi cut out